# Checkbox in Wordpress theme options

Tags: wordpress-theming

I'm trying to implement a simple checkbox to toggle an option in my Wordpress theme, but it's not working. Here's what I have:

In the form...

```
<input type="checkbox" class="display-twitter" name="display-twitter" id="display-twitter" value="true"<?php if ( true == $options['display-twitter'] ) { echo ' checked="checked"'; } ?>> <?php _e( 'Display your Twitter Feed?', 'crate' ); ?>
```

In the function to sanitize my input...

```
function theme_options_validate( $input ) {  
        ...  
        $input['display-twitter'] = ( isset( $input['display-twitter'] ) ? false : true );  
        ...  
        return $input;  
}
```

When checking the box the first time to enable the option, all works fine. But then when I check it again, I get `Notice: Undefined index: display-twitter ...` thrown at me.

What gives? Something to do with the ternary?

Comment: Could you post the form again. Seems to have vanished!

Comment: OK, I see it now. Give me a minute.

Comment: Oh man.  Because this is Wordpress, with all it’s custom code I’m not sure what’s going on without seeing the entire page.

Comment: It would be too much code to display, but essentially the form passes the data to the function `register_setting()` which in turn validates all the data through `theme_options_validate()` and saves to the database. My problem is that I can check the box to turn it off, but once it's off the validation doesn't accept the checkbox data (because the only data is `value="true"` and once it's off it doesn't pass data). I just don't know how to work the ternary to accept `false`... if any of this makes sense :(

Comment: Ok.. in that case, store the false value in a `$_SESSION` on the event that turns it off, then write an `if` statement to `echo` that false out from there when you go to turn to back on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you should be using the isset function, this will check if the variable is set and is not NULL, however a checkbox always has 2 states so can never be NULL, that's why the output is always true.

Correct function would be the following, I believe:

```
function theme_options_validate( $input ) {  
    ...  
    $input['display-twitter'] = ($input['display-twitter'] ? false : true        );  
    ...  
    return $input;  
}
```